# Sparql query to get all classes that are subclass of a "property class"

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, protege

I need to "annotate" some classes by adding a property to them. I need to do that in order to let the view layer of my application extract the correct classes.

What I have done is:

create an object property called **uiProperty** and edit these classes to make them subclass of this class:

```
uiProperty some
```

So the final OWL code for my classes is something like this:

```
rdfs:subClassOf owebs:RealEstate ,
                                [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                  owl:onProperty owebs:uiProperty ;
                                  owl:someValuesFrom owl:Thing
                                ] ;
```

Now I want to build a sparql query to get these classes. I did the following:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owbes: <http://www.isep.org/desco/2015/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

SELECT $uri $label WHERE {
    $uri rdfs:subClassOf owbes:RealEstate.
    $uri rdfs:subClassOf $x.
    $x owl:onProperty owbes:uiProperty.
    $uri rdfs:label $label
}
```

#### The problem

The result of that query is too many classes. The same class is being repeated many times. For example:

[image]

#### My question

Why did that happen?
and how to solve it?

Comment: What happens if you `SELECT distinct $uri $label WHERE ...`?  The result is kind of odd though.  Maybe you're using a reasoner, and getting one result per way that the reasoner is inferring that Villa has that type, or something?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor for sure using `distinct` solves the problem. I am using Fuseki sparql endpoint. However, I would like to know the reason of those strange results. Plus, maybe I am using the `subClassOf` in a wrong way. I don't know

Comment: Without seeing your data, I don't know that we can answer that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to "annotate" some classes by adding a property to them. I need
>   to do that in order to let the view layer of my application extract
>   the correct classes.

That's actually what *annotation properties*, such as rdfs:label, are for. You can define your own annotation properties, and then retrieve the classes with SPARQL more directly by querying for those.  For instance, here's an ontology with three special classes:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="urn:ex:"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/taylorj/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-45"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:ex:C">
    <j.0:isSpecialClass rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">true</j.0:isSpecialClass>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:ex:A">
    <j.0:isSpecialClass rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">true</j.0:isSpecialClass>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="urn:ex:B"/>
  <owl:AnnotationProperty rdf:about="urn:ex:isSpecialClass"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: and please why am i having these strange duplicates? is there any solution rather than distinct  ?

Comment: sorry so you meant that I am using `uiProperty some` in a wrong way?

Comment: I have to go, I will be back in one hour, sorry , i hope we can continue after one hour

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Well, if the point it just to identify some classes, then you probably don't really want to be making logical assertions about them.  Saying that "A subclassof [some uiProperty]" means that every instance of the class A has a value for the property uiProperty.  Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: no I didn't want to say that, I just want to let some classes have a property in order to extract them using a sparql query. I am doing that because I need to make a dynamic presentation layer. So, I need to annotate some classes in order to select them later. Did you get me please?

Comment: Then I think my answer is pretty much what you're looking for.  Just define a new annotation property like I did, annotate your classes, and then you can query for classes that have that property.